# How much is too much for Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am working on a community site powered by Joomla. The site will have

1. News/Information (2 to 3 articles added weekly)
2. Social Media (Easy Social 1.4) - Can grow upto 20,000 registered members sharing photos, status daily
3. Directory (J Business Directory) - Entries upto 10,000 businesses
4. Shopping Multi vender (VirtueMart) - upto 2000 items
5. Blog (Easy Blog)

I know it is advised to have them on different installations and configure Jfusion to have one login for all but I cannot do that for the following reasons

1. Since it is a community site striving to be a one stop for all the needs of this particular community, everything needs to be integrated. Ex. When the user comments on an article or post a review on the directory, his profile is seen which links to his social media account on this site.
2. The home page of the site will have modules from all the components. Ex: Directory Search Module, Social Media Registration module etc.

MY QUESTIONS:

- Q1: Do you think a single Joomla installation can handle this? And for how long?
- Q2: The site will be on a shared hosting at the beginning. Do I need a VPS for this site and when?
- Q3: Do I need cloud services and CDN services and when? Will the free Cloudflare service do?

Answer (score 4):

**Do you think a single Joomla installation can handle this? And for how long?**

Yes, I single Joomla installation can handle this. You will need to consider using a good hosting provider such as SiteGround and with the possibility of requiring a small dedicated server for the future. My site has over 37,000 registered users and the [Siteground GrowBig](https://www.siteground.com/web-hosting.htm) shared hosting package suits me fine for the time being.

---

**The site will be on a shared hosting at the beginning. Do I need a VPS for this site and when?**

Knowing when to migrate over to a VPS or dedicated server will have to be determined by yourself. Whichever hosting provider you go with, be sure to regularly check the server statistics, such as CPU usage, requests and server space. As your site continues to grow, these stats will increase. Whether your hosting provider contacts you saying you're causing issues for user on the server or your stats are in the "orange" zone, this will be the time.

---

**Do I need cloud services and CDN services and when? Will the free Cloudflare service do?**

I would definitely recommend using a CDN. All Siteground shared hosting packages come with free Cloudflare access which you can utilize.

---

**The big "MUST":**

Please make sure you experiment with caching as it sounds like you're definitely going to need it.

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm not endorsed with SiteGround, nor were any affiliate links used.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much Lodder!!  that was really helpful..  I would still be interested in hearing from other folks  :)

Comment: Is your site using a social media component like easysocial or jomsocial??  users sharing contents everyday?

Comment: @fmstatic59 - Nope, not using any of that